# old paper wallet shows missing balance after import; hacked? Bug? Confused?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, paper-wallet

I have an old (2014) paper wallet I've deposited coins into over the years.  I have another paper wallet that was generated around the same time, but wasn't used until last year.  I just finished syncing Bitcoin Core and imported the keys from the paper wallet, first the older key without rescan, then the newer key with rescan.

After a rescan, I'm not seeing the expected balance.

I've been monitoring the old wallet with the [Samourai Sentinel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samourai.sentinel&hl=en_US&gl=US) app.  This app shows a balance of 8 BTC at the address.  When clicking through, the app takes me to: [1PMoUJpj73FUTbjMiKwJfJoo4fJaUE9bTr](http://srv1.yogh.io/address/1PMoUJpj73FUTbjMiKwJfJoo4fJaUE9bTr/).  This looks about right, and like what I expect. *(for some reason, the link doesn't work direct, but navigating to http://srv1.yogh.io and entering the address brings it up; cookie related probably)*

But in Bitcoin Core, I don't see the balance.  I do see the balance for the newer wallet, which has 2 BTC in it here: [1LwpoTZwuS8Yw5T9EdnnHemmqQ46jCUznK](http://srv1.yogh.io/address/1LwpoTZwuS8Yw5T9EdnnHemmqQ46jCUznK/).

```
$ bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress
[
  {
    "address": "14H7dShaq6CGtyZQujckNSswac7tM5CMjE",
    "amount": 7.00850502,
    "confirmations": 388012,
    "label": "",
    "txids": [
      "d7896aa4f8bc3cb40c7abc5e388f9f505b607a57b73a0ab6594355eb6977155e",
      "ecc0149be32a31f721ed722b6788773796c627bfc6edab6dcd6242a4cd0f2a5e",
      "8a0ac886cff7af925be4df890e0fddc44929bd781716661c1706536c92d74789"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address": "1LwpoTZwuS8Yw5T9EdnnHemmqQ46jCUznK",
    "amount": 1.99645000,
    "confirmations": 33899,
    "label": "",
    "txids": [
      "783042888dc68a52379f4905260ee3e457524ce7a1738d0d1dbdf2f5a7e84016",
      "14e16a88bab62f5a40580635ed4476e0859ecf36f943488afb15f838f2c307d4"
    ]
  }
]
```

The second address matches my newer paper wallet, but the first address doesn't match the older wallet, and it looks like it's been completely spent.  These transactions predate those I expect and see in 1PMoUJpj73FUTbjMiKwJfJoo4fJaUE9bTr, so it's possible this was a key re-used by mistake, but my memory doesn't go that far back.

Can someone explain what's going on?  Did I mess up somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

> in Bitcoin Core, I don't see the balance.

Blockchain explorers do confirm that address [1PMoUJpj73FUTbjMiKwJfJoo4fJaUE9bTr](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/1PMoUJpj73FUTbjMiKwJfJoo4fJaUE9bTr) still holds 8 BTC. So that suggests there has been no hacking or improper removal of money.

---

> first the older key without rescan,

I would re-import the older key *with* rescan. I would also make sure the wallet has completely synchronised. I would independently confirm that the  1PMoUJpj73FUTbjMiKwJfJoo4fJaUE9bTr address can actually be generated from the keys of your original paper wallet.

---

> The second address matches my newer paper wallet, but the first address doesn't match the older wallet

Perhaps something went wrong when you attempted to import the older key? Maybe you have a third paper wallet whose details you lost or mislaid or accidentally swapped with the original?